# Python - Two processes after compiling?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I'm currently working on a small python script, for controlling my home PC (really just a hobby project - nothing serious).

Inside the script, there is two threads running at the same time using thread (might start using threading instead) like this:

```
thread.start_new_thread( Function, (Args) )
```

Its works as intended when testing the script... but after compiling the code using Pyinstaller there are two processes (One for each thread - I think).

How do I fix this?

Comment: [PyInstaller manual: How one-file mode works](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#how-one-file-mode-works)

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Just kill the loader from the main program if it really bothers you. Here's one way to do it.

```
import os
import win32com.client

proc_name = 'MyProgram.exe'
my_pid = os.getpid()

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')
all_procs = wmi.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

for proc in all_procs:
   if proc.Properties_("Name").Value == proc_name:
        proc_pid = proc.Properties_("ProcessID").Value
        if proc_pid != my_pid:
            print "killed my loader %s\n" % (proc_pid)
            os.kill(proc_pid, 9)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python code does not need to be "compiled with pyinstaller"

Products like "Pyinstaller" or "py2exe" are usefull to create a single executable file that you can distribute to third parties, or relocate inside your computer without worrying about the Python instalation - however, they don add "speed" nor is the resulting binary file any more "finished" than your original .py (or .pyw on Windows) file.

What these products do is to create another copy of the Python itnrepreter, alogn with all the modules your porgram use, and pack them inside a single file. It is likely the Pyinstaller keep a second process running to check things on the main script (like launching it, maybe there are options on it to keep the script running and so on). This is not part of a standard Python program.

It is not likely Pyinstaller splits the threads into 2 separate proccess as that would cause compatibility problems - thread run on the same process and can transparently access the same data structures.

How a "canonical" Python program runs: the main process, seen by the O.S. is the Python binary (Python.exe on Windows) - it finds the Python script it was called for - if there is a ".pyc" file for it, that is loaded - else, it loads your ".py" file and compiles that to Python byte code (not to windwos executable). This compilation is authomatic and transparent to people running the program. It is analogous to a Java compile from a .java file to a .class - but there is no explicit step needed by the programmer or user -  it is made in place - and other factors control wether Python will store the resulting bytecode as .pyc file or not.

To sum up: there is no performance impact in running the ".py" script directly instead of generating an .exe file with Pyinstaller or other product. You have a disk-space usage inpact if you do, though, as you will have one copy of the Python interpreter and libraries for each of your scripts.

The URL pointeded by Janne Karila on the comment nails it -  its even worse than I thought:
in order to run yioru script, pyinstaller unpacks Python DLLs and modules in a temporary directory. The time and system resources needed todo that, compared with a single script run is non-trivial.
http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#how-one-file-mode-works

Comment: Thanks for the lecture... But it still doesn't bring me any closer to why the script suddenly creates two processes when made into a standalone executable. Here is a list of modules imported in the script: pythoncom, pyHook, urllib2, time, smtplib, getpass, random, thread, os, psutil, subprocess, math, wmi, inspect, pythoncom, shutil, win32con, win32api, sys, platform (currently trying to reduce the amount af imported modules...)

Comment: The link at the end, provided by Janne states why there are two processes: """ When first started, it finds that it needs to extract these files before it can run "for real" (...) It then executes itself again. """ Anyway, I don't think these two proccesses are relevant: it should be quite clear from the explanations above that you should not be using Pyinstaller to begin with.